# How to get a node's depth in a tree using DFS?

Tags: tree, depth-first-search

I've encountered a problem to print out an entire tree. Of course the traversal is easy:

```
    public static void printTree(Node head){
    if(head == null) return;
    System.out.println(head.data);
    printTree(head.left);
    printTree(head.right);
}
```

However, the problem states that I should print the depth of the node along with its data. Say if the tree's root is A and its children are B and C respectively, then I should print something like:
0 A
1 B
1 C
How can I do that?
I am new to recursion and I don't really know how can I keep track of the depth while recursing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Try adding another parameter to your function to track the depth.

public static void printTree(Node head) {
  printTreeHelper(head, 0);
}

private static void printTreeHelper(Node head, int curDepth) {
  if (head == null) return;
  System.out.println(curDepth + head.data);
  printTree(head.left, depth + 1);
  printTree(head.right, depth + 1);
}
```

Of course, you do not need to use the helper and can just make printTree take in the depth, but just in case that is the interface you have to use, the helper method will let you continue to use it.

Answer (score 0):

After some considerations you can notice that the depth of a node is equal to the depth of recursion when the node is discovered. So, you can add parameter to your recursive function that indicates depth of recursion.

```
public static void printTree(Node head, int depth){
    if(head == null) return;
    System.out.println(depth + " " + head.data);
    printTree(head.left, depth + 1);
    printTree(head.right, depth + 1);
}
```

Naturally, you run the function as: `printTree(node, 0);`